# How to use quotes effectively in cygwin?

Tags: bash, batch-file, cygwin, quotes

```
2.bat calls 3.bash "cmd /c "path to command with spaces""
```

3.bash contains

```
cmd="$1"
"$cmd"
```

I'm using `cmd /c command` because when the bash script runs it doesn't recognise that command as executable, so I have to launch it with cmd /c. However, this creates another problem with quoting.

```
+ cmd='cmd /c "c:\program'
```

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You should escape inner quotes:

```
3.bash "cmd /c \"path to command with spaces\""
```

Also you may use command `cygpath` instead of `cmd`

```
#3.bash
"`cygpath -u "$1"`"
```

and the command

```
3.bash "path to command with spaces"
```

Comment: Escaping the inner quotes produces: `cmd /c "path to command with spaces": No such file or directory.` Using cygpath -u "$1" works, but I'd rather work on getting the first solution to work because I'd prefer to minimally alter the bash script.

Comment: are you sure cmd is in path??? Because cmd error for not found file looks this way: `'path to command with spaces' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: Yes, if you're asking whether "path to command with spaces" is correct. cygpath -u works with the same path.

Comment: No, i've asked if "cmd is in path". "cmd" command. Cygwin seems to be saying it can't find "cmd" command, so try full path, e.g. `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/cmd` (can be different for your system)

Comment: I think it's in the path; 'which cmd' produces /cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/cmd. I tried using that, but it results in the same error. It seems that bash interprets the full command as a path, not as a command followed by a path. It also works if I prefix "$cmd" with eval: eval "$cmd".